# Customising the Text Field

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

So - I am experimenting at the moment with app design.

This is my concept: [image: Concept]

See the blue line? That should be where the users "cursor" starts and cant go negativaly behind that point, but can move positively until the end of the box.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question or did you just want to know if we can see the blue line (caret)?

Comment: @maddy actually as much as I hate to say it - no. I am looking more for the customisation (which can be done through methods within the code, so to an extent yes -> **what methods are available?**) and how can I make the text field start there rather than over the `Username:` field

Comment: Have you read the reference docs on `UITextField`?

Comment: @maddy yep and I cannot find anything referencing the position of the text (padding, alignment etc)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the UITextField starts after the colon and does not extend beyond the cell's trailing edge, you should have no issues. Are you laying out using code or Interface Builder?

Comment: Hey, im laying out in the IB, when I do it like that the text box is actually maybe -50 - -100 px above the image, is it better to do it through code?

Comment: What do you mean by "above the image"? Could you post a screenshot of your IB?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the similar UI using UITableview. Code to set the Username label for the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath (use similar code for Password row):

```
tableViewCell.textLabel.text = @"Username:";
```

Here is the code to set the text field:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textFieldRect];
//Insert code for text field delegate and properties e.g. keyboardType, autocorrectionType

tableViewCell.accessoryView = textField;
```